# runtimeException at mediaRecorder.start() on android at version 4.0.3

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder

I have this code for capturing video on android. But this code throws a `RuntimeException`. I searched for that but I couldnt get a response. Log is:

```
errorrrrrrrrr runtime44444444444!!!
```

what line has error???

```
private void startRecording()  
    {

         mCamera.unlock();
         mrec = new MediaRecorder(); 
         mrec.setCamera(mCamera); 

         mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
         mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

         mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

         mrec.setVideoFrameRate(24);
         mrec.setVideoSize(720, 480);

         Method[] methods =   mrec.getClass().getMethods();
         for (Method method: methods){
                try
                {
                    if(method.getName().equals("setAudioEncodingBitRate"))
                    {
                       method.invoke(mrec,12200);
                    }
                    else if(method.getName().equals("setVideoEncodingBitRate"))
                    {
                        method.invoke(mrec, 3000000);
                    }
                    else if(method.getName().equals("setAudioSamplingRate"))
                    {
                        method.invoke(mrec,8000);
                    }
                    else if(method.getName().equals("setVideoFrameRate"))
                    {
                        method.invoke(mrec,24);
                    }

                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (InvocationTargetException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (RuntimeException e) 
                 {
                    Log.d("errorrrrrrrrr runtime111111111", "okkkkkkkkkk");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }

         mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
         mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

         mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());   
         mrec.setOrientationHint(90); 

         mrec.setOutputFile(Videopath);

         try 
         {
             mrec.prepare();

         } 
         catch (IllegalStateException e) 
         {
           //  releaseRecorder();
          //   return false;
         } 
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
          //   releaseRecorder();
           //  return false;
         }
         catch (RuntimeException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
          //  return false;
         }


         try
         {
             mrec.start(); 
         }
         catch (RuntimeException e) 
         {
            Log.d("errorrrrrrrrr runtime44444444444", "okkkkkkkkkk");

            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
          //  return false;
            Log.d("errorrrrrrrrr 33333333333", "okkkkkkkkkk");

         }
         isRecording=true;
        // return true;
    }
```

Comment: add the stacktrace please.

Comment: I havent any stacktrace! but I only know start() calling makes exception.how i resolve ?

Comment: and i must tell this code run perfectly on sumsong galaxy version 2.2

Comment: you have a "e.printstacktrace" in your exception handler. So you need to use logcat to see what that exception is. I'm going to guess you are using an unsupported: encoder, frame rate, video size or any combination of those mistakes. You're hard coding a lot of things there and you probably shouldn't be. You also need to learn about Java programming in general and some android dev stuff too. Do some more research/homework.